# Resample a data frame into n-month periods with arbitrary end-of-period months

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I want to `resample()` my daily data into six-month chunks. However, I want the ends of the six-month chunks to be the ends of April and October. If I use `df.resample('6M').sum()` (or `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='6M').sum()`), the end of the first six-month chunk is the end of the first month in the data. I know about [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets), but I do not know how to create a custom anchored offset (e.g., `'6M-APR'` does not work).

Here is some example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'logret': np.random.randn(1000)},
    index=pd.date_range(start='2001-05-25', periods=1000, freq='B')
)
df.resample('6M').sum()
```

Which yields the following output:

```
    logret
2001-05-31  2.2950148716254297
2001-11-30  -12.536360930670858
2002-05-31  5.468848462868161
2002-11-30  13.027927629740189
2003-05-31  -10.37282118563155
2003-11-30  -0.156275418330286
2004-05-31  -3.0768727498370905
2004-11-30  28.328856464071546
2005-05-31  -3.6462613215100546
```

I have not achieved my goal (six-month resampling that ends in April and October) with the `start`, `offset`, and `loffset` arguments to `.resample()`.

I have achieved my goal with the hack below. However, it loses the date index, and I would like a more robust/repeatable approach.

```
def sixmonth(d, b=4):
    y, m, h = d.year, d.month, 1
    if (m > (b + 6)): y += 1
    elif (m > b): h += 1

    return y + h/10

df.groupby(sixmonth).sum()
```

Which yields the following output without a date:

```
    logret
2001.2  -10.300839024148
2002.1  9.321994034984547
2002.2  8.855517878860585
2003.1  -2.4576797445001493
2003.2  -7.002919570231796
2004.1  -9.36895555474087
2004.2  27.13038641177464
2005.1  3.154551390326532
```

Of course, I could improve this hack. But is there a better/robust/repeatable solution for n-period resampling that ends in arbitrary months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another workaround, keeping the datetime index:

```
def custom_6M(df, month=4):
    df = df.resample("M").sum()
    df = df.rolling(6).sum()
    return df[df.index.month.isin([month,month+6])]

>>> custom_6M(df)
               logret
2001-10-31 -10.300839
2002-04-30   9.321994
2002-10-31   8.855518
2003-04-30  -2.457680
2003-10-31  -7.002920
2004-04-30  -9.368956
2004-10-31  27.130386
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pain. When I needed something similar, I ended up with the following approach:

```
anchor_month = 4
non_months = (anchor_month + 3) % 12, (anchor_month + 9) % 12
df = df.resample('Q-APR').sum()
df = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby(df.index.month.isin(non_months).cumsum())
        .agg({'index': 'last', 'logret': 'sum'})
        .set_index('index'))
```

Result here:

```
               logret
index                
2001-10-31 -10.300839
2002-04-30   9.321994
2002-10-31   8.855518
2003-04-30  -2.457680
2003-10-31  -7.002920
2004-04-30  -9.368956
2004-10-31  27.130386
2005-04-30   3.154551
```

But the problem is, that sometimes the last index doesn't fit (okay here). That can be fixed by another `'6M'`-resample. Overall: Not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.
I have two more options.

##### Append a time-stamped series to `df` to anchor the six-month resampling periods

I hoped that `.resample()`'s `origin` argument would let me manually anchor my six-month resampling periods. It doesn't, but the following code does.

```
df.append(pd.Series(name=pd.to_datetime('2001-04-30'), dtype='float')).resample('6M').sum()
```

##### Improve my `sixmonth()` function to use timestamps

```
def sixmonth(d, m=6, n=4):
    o = (m - (d.month - n)) % m
    return d + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(o)
```

I first `.resample('M')` to make sure that I have end-of-month dates.
I could modify `sixmonth()` to check for end-of-month dates, but I'm more afraid of finding some new edge case than a little inefficiency.

```
df.resample('M').sum().groupby(sixmonth).sum()
```